# IcCube - alter schema and reports from shell

Tags: shell, iccube

In the icCube.4.0 folder is all the information stored of the IcCube server. If I change a icc-schema file, the changes will take effect after the next restart of the server.

Is it possible, to do some changes on files in this folder, which take immediate effect, or is there a function I can use on the shell, to put those changes into the server?
Also is there a similar option for reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different scenarios when changing a file directly from the file system :

- If you changed the files in ( {}/cubes ), then the latest file version will be used when the schema is loaded. To see the latest version in the UI you can refresh the panel as described below.
- If you changed the files in ( {}/builder ) and you're using the IDE you've to refresh manually the 'SCHEMA MANAGER' panel, it's the little wheel in the right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Is there something similar for Reports, so can I somehow find the reports in icCube.4.0 somewhere, or do I have to Export the report via Browser, modify and import again?

Comment: @ic3 -  `mdx` tag has been proposed for documentation - can you add your vote please as we need several votes to create the documentation for this tag: stackoverflow.com/documentation/mdx

Comment: @Ulrich: this is currently not possible; reports are saved into a JCR repository.